# React: Uncaught TypeError: animes.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, anime.js

I'm new to React and I'm doing an Anime project. I've managed to get the values of the animes from the Jikan API with the map function. But the url's correspond to for example "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/genres/anime" or "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime?filter=bypopularity", but if i change that same url to a specific character (for example: "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/people/5579") or a specific movie (for example "https://api.jikan.moe/v4 /anime/38000") tells me that "animes.map is not a function". I've verified that the parameters are correct. I would appreciate your help.

````
const getAnimes = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/people/5579');
    const animes = await response.json();
    return animes;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

function App() {
  const [animes, setAnimes] = useState([]);

  const fetchAnimes = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await getAnimes();
      setAnimes(data.data);
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAnimes();
  }, []);

  return (
    // <React.Fragment>
    <>
      <header>
        <h1>Search Anime</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
        <article className="countries">
          {animes.map((anime) => (
            <div key={anime.mal_id}>
              <h2>{anime.name}</h2>
            </div>
          ))}
        </article>
      </main>
    </>
    // </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;```
````

Comment: because it is not iterable,  its already one item

Comment: Try console.log(YOUR ARRAY) when things like that happens. You'll know if your variable actually contains an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a people Id directly then you need to remove `map`

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

---

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const getAnimes = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/people/5579');
    const animes = await response.json();
    return animes;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

function App() {
  const [animes, setAnimes] = useState([]);

  const fetchAnimes = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await getAnimes();
      setAnimes(data.data);
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAnimes();
  }, []);

  return (
    // <React.Fragment>
    <>
      <header>
        <h1>Search Anime</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
        <article className="countries">
            <div key={animes.mal_id}>
              <h2>{animes.name}</h2>
              { console.log(animes) }
            </div>
        </article>
      </main>
    </>
    // </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: Sorry, but in the case of movies (for example "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/5114/") the error is "Failed to fetch".

Comment: you have an extra `"`  you want this `https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/5114/`

Comment: Sorry to bother you dippas again, but in the code modification you made (without .map), if we introduce images, for example: <div key={animes.mal_id}>
             <h2>{animes.name}</h2>
             <img src={animes.images.jpg.image_url} alt="Img" />
             {console.log(animes)}
           </div>
it displays the image once, but if you refresh the browser it returns the following error: "App.js:37: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jpg')" How could I solve it? Thank you again.

Comment: Solved. It simply lacked an optional chaining. By not using map method, it does not create a new array with the results of the call to the indicated function applied to each of its elements. So once the browser is refreshed it returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jpg')". Example: <img src={animes.images?.jpg.image_url} alt="Img" />

Comment: I've updated the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-sutherland-rpx874), and yes exactly, it is `?.` optional chaining the way to fix it, sorry for the delay, I just woke up

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @dippas. I have already set the answer as valid. Now I'm just starting with JS and Reactu and I hope one day to have a good level and be able to help others as you have done.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support both The https://api.jikan.moe/v4/genres/anime search and
specific character like https://api.jikan.moe/v4/people/5579 Then on the response time you can check whether response you get is an array or not, If its not you can convert it to an array so your

```
{animes.map((anime) => (
        <div key={anime.mal_id}>
          <h2>{anime.name}</h2>
        </div>
      ))}
```

does not get breaks, here how you can do that

```
    const getAnimes = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/people/5579');
    let animes = await response.json();
    if (!Array.isArray(animes)) {
      animes = [animes]
    }
    return animes;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

but though it is not a good practice to do in that way. You should have a page which lists all animes and when a user click on a single anime you should have a separate page for it, it will help to have a more deterministic approach.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `map` an `object` not an `array` which is not possible. If you want to get all `people` information, you should remove the `id` from `api` call then it will work fine.

```
const response = await fetch("https://api.jikan.moe/v4/people");
```

Here is the working version without `id`  https://codesandbox.io/embed/thirsty-feistel-yjs6my?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark.

Instead if you want to use single people object, just remove the `map` part